# arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF fails to render layer?

Tags: arcpy, rendering, mapping

Has anyone else had this problem?

I have an mxd file with two layers in it, one of which is fairly 'heavy' (i.e. takes a minute or so to draw). All layers are visible by default.

I have the following code, which opens the mxd file (from outside arcmap) and exports it to a tiff.

```
import arcpy   
template = r"C:\mxd_templates\template1.mxd"  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(template)  
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, "C:/temp/test.tif")
```

The tif file is created, but the second 'heavy' layer is never rendered.
This happens no matter what image format I export to.

I've not found anywhere to be able to report bugs online, and I'm having a hard time to get ESRI to recognise this as a bug or to point out what I am doing wrong. Although it is hard to see what could possibly be wrong in 4 lines of code?

Same behaviour on 10.1, 10.2 and 10.2.2, 64bit. The layer that does not render is a raster in arcSDE.
The layer that does render is a raster in a file GDB

---

In response to comments below, Yes the map does export correctly when rendered manually via arcmap, and yes the layers are correctly ordered and have been thoroughly checked.

Comment: does it render correctly when you manually create the tif inside arcmap using export? If not I would look at the layer order in the mxd for a first step. it seems you would have already done this but you don't specify that you have in your question.

Comment: Yes, it renders correctly when manually exporting.

Comment: Please add to question not in comments

Comment: Have you tried adding a time.sleep(60) to make it wait a minute between opening the MXD and exporting? I'm not sure if the processes are asynchronous, so maybe it's drawing in the background while you export. Easy to try at least.

Comment: @MWrenn. Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately didn't work. Still get the same result even with a 2 minute sleep

Comment: Is the raster that is not displaying in the same coordinate system as the dataframe? Also have you tried ExportToPNG, ExportToPDF or ExportToJPEG with similar results?

Comment: Trying to reproduce this would seem to be very straightforward if using the same data as you.  Have you offered to provide it to Esri's Technical Support?  Also, like @BradNesom, I think you should try reversing the draw order of your layers *as a test* to see whether it is the particular layer or the order in which they are drawing which causes its non-appearance.

Comment: Pyramids being drawn manually but not in the code? I like this idea as it is the larger layer not being drawn. You may have pyramids on by default in ArcGIS hence the extended rendering time. So when you manually bring it in is is building pyramids!

Comment: @James, Not a required argument, but have you tried to include the dataframe reference in the arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF method?

Comment: @MWrenn, it is the same coordinate system for all layers in the DF and the DF itself. I get the same results with all Export methods

Comment: @PolyGeo The data is proprietary so I can't give it away, although we may make an exception for Tech Support. Unfortunately, despite my nattering I have not got a response from ESRI as of yet..I've been referred to someone who apparently doesn't want to get in touch.

Comment: @PolyGeo, revising the order made no difference :(. I'm assuming it has something to do with either/both the fact that the layers are 'heavy' and they are coming from a remote SDE server (well, next room), rather than the local computer

Comment: I don't know the service level agreements in all countries, but when I last managed an Esri support team if you were on Maintenance and had not been contacted back by someone technical within 4 business hours we considered it poor service.